# C Remove first element in a list

Tags: c, list, struct

I've got a structure:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node List;
```

And I've implemented adding items to the list but I've got problem with removing element from the list when it's the first element on given list, my function:

```
void removeItem(List *ptr, int i)
{
    List *current = ptr;
    List *prev = NULL;
while (current != NULL)
{
    if (current->value == i)
    {
                    //it's first element
        if (prev == NULL)
        {
            List *replace = ptr->next;
            free(current);
            ptr = replace;
            current = replace;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = prev->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
}
```

When my list is like:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

After using *removeItem(list, 1)* it's:

> 0, 2, 3, 4, 5

*0* shouldn't be there.

Another question is that I should also implement those functions when typedef is different:

```
typedef struct Node *List;
```

But then I get tons of "wrong argument type" / "request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union" errors. Can I find some example of how this should be handled?

Comment: `ptr = replace;` has no effect out of the scope of the function.

Comment: Right but ptr = ptr->next; has the same effect (1 replaced by 0)

Comment: I mean `ptr = <any other stuff here, regardless of what it is>;` has no effect, since `ptr` is local to the variable. Read up on scopes in C, I'm getting tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the variable that you pass in (`list`) does not get modified by your remove code. Thus, when you remove the first `Node` in your `List`, you're left with a reference to a `Node` that is no longer in your `List`.

The reason is this:

When you call `removeItem(list, 1)`, you're passing in the value of `list`. In this case, it's an address of data with type `List`. Inside the `removeItem` function, that value is carried by the `ptr` variable. When you enter the function, the `ptr` variable is the address of your `List` and you do your work with it. In the line `ptr = replace`, all you're doing is changing the value held by `ptr`. It does not affect the value of `list` within the scope that `removeItem` was called.

The simplest thing to do would be for `removeList` to return a pointer to the head of the resulting list. For most calls, it will be the same as the incoming `ptr`; only when the removed `Node` is at the head of the `List`, will the resulting pointer be different.

Alternatively, you could change `removeList` so that it requires a pointer to a pointer to a `List`, then you would call it as `removeList(&list, 1)` and this would allow you to modify the value in `list` directly.

Answer (score 1):

This loooks like a homework problem, so I don't want to give a direct answer, but  are two clues:

- if your goal is to change what the list points to in the function calling `removeItem()`, what does the type of the first argument of `removeItem()` need to be?
- if I told you that in some implementations, `free()`ing a pointer variable zeroes out the space pointed to by that variable as an aid to debugging, would that help you understand the output you're getting?

Please feel free to post an answer to your own question when you get this working.

Answer (score 0):

All answers were helpful, this is a final function:

```
void removeItem(List *ptr, int i)
{
    while ((*ptr) != NULL)
    {
        if ((*ptr)->value == i)
        {
            List tmp = *ptr;
            *ptr = (*ptr)->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
        }
    }
}
```

Works as it should:

```
List ptr = malloc(sizeof(List));

//add items to list:
//1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5,

removeItem(&ptr, 5);
removeItem(&ptr, 2);
removeItem(&ptr, 1);

//print and clean
//3, 4, 4,
```